# Capturing "Tab" key press by both the focused component and its container

Tags: java, swing, tabs

Is there a way to propagate a key press from say a `JTextField` to its container's `KeyListener` implementation?

So in effect, the keypress would be acted upon by both the text field and the `JPanel`. Right now the text field is consuming the key press so is nonexistent to the `JPanel` underneath.

Comment: in particular Im looking to capture the "Tab" keypress

Comment: tab has special meaning in Java Swing applications and is usually governed by the [focus subsystem](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) and its [FocusTraversalPolicy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FocusTraversalPolicy.html)

Answer (score 2):

In Swing, the <kbd>tab</kbd> key is used to change the focus from one component to another. The article [*Validating Input*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) discusses `InputVerifier`, which may help you do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The question is why do you want to do this? What is your actual requirement as oppose to your attempted solution. Having an event handled by two components is generally not a good idea.

In general you should not use KeyListeners. Swing was designed to use [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). However, in this case it won't help because as mentioned earlier the focus subsystem handles the tab key.

If this is the only solution to your problem, then I think you can use  `KeyEventPostProcessor` to listen for any KeyEvent. See [Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) for more info.

Comment: I've built a class that contain various swing input components (JTextFields, JComboBox, JLabel, etc) all within a JPanel with the height of a conventional toolbar.  If there are too many widgets added to the bar some of the components will be hidden off screen.  Since users will use the Tab key to hop from component to component I wanted to capture the Tab key press by the underlying JPanel so if they attempt to "Tab" to a component off the screen it will trigger a "shift" of all components to the left and relayout the panel, and have the previously hidden component visible and focused.